# How to can solved the MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2195' issue?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I am doing a java program to connect to QMGR on z/OS, so, I'm using a binding mode connection, cause the client mode is not enable inside of OS. When I run the jar file It's throwed the next stack trace:

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2195'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.<init>(MQSESSION.java:2064)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.getSession(MQSESSION.java:2104)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:213)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:191)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:237)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:874)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:822)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:764)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:871)
```

With the next posible cause:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.NullPointerException[null],3=LocalMQ.get390Adapter64]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:804)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:676)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.<init>(MQSESSION.java:2057)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.get390Adapter64(LocalMQ.java:826)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:258)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:220)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1261)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:742)
    ... 61 more
```

This is the java code to create the QMGR and queue connection:

```
MQEnvironment.CCSID=500;
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQConstants.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS);
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.APPNAME_PROPERTY, "DLQReport");

        //Crete the queue manager connection            
        queueManager = new MQQueueManager(mqQMGR);

        //Set the mq queue manager options connection. This connection will be in browse mode only without delete the messages
        //in the queue.
        int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQConstants.MQOO_BROWSE;

        //Set the get message options
        gmo.options = MQConstants.MQGMO_WAIT | MQConstants.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
        gmo.matchOptions = MQConstants.MQMO_NONE;
        gmo.waitInterval = 5000;

        //Create the queue connection
        MQQueue queue = queueManager.accessQueue(dlqName, openOptions);
```

Seems I solved this issue changing the next line:

```
MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQConstants.MQCNO_STANDARD_BINDING);
```

But right now I have this issue:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.determineTransport(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:917)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:864)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:822)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:764)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:871)
```

Any idea?

Comment: 2195 is MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR. Look in the SYSLOG of your MSTR address space of your z/OS queue manager to see what it says - probably an abend of some sort.

Comment: I also see this text `LocalMQ.get390Adapter64` in your error. I don't know what it means, but perhaps it is a hint that you are using the wrong bitness?

Comment: Can you confirm this java application is running on z/OS with the queue manager?  I see you tagged this question with both [spring-boot] and with [ibm-integration-bus], can you explain how one or both of those technologies applies to your situation?  Can you confirm which version of MQ jar files you are using?

Comment: I tagged this question with both technologies because maybe some IIB developer have had similar issues some time... the java version that I'm using is IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 z/OS s390x-64-Bit Compressed References 20191106_432135 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)

Comment: Which IBM MQ jar file version are you using?  You should stick to tags that are directly related to your question.  You should provide minimal sample of java JMS code that causes the error for you.

Comment: Questions: (1) Are you running the Java program as a z/OS batch job or under USS? (2) Is the Java program running in the same LPAR as the queue manager? (3) Is the Java program uses the MQ JAR files for z/OS and not from Windows or Unix? (4) If running as z/OS batch job, what DSNs do you have in your STEPLIB?  (6)  If running as a  USS script, do you have the ***-Djava.library.path={MQ_INSTALL_DIR}/java/lib*** path set on the java command?

Comment: The idea is run it using a batch job, but right now I'm running it directly with the jar file to test it. The java program is running in the same LPAR as the QMGR. The java version is definately for z/OS. When I run the jar file I added the -Djava.library.path={MQ_INSTALL_DIR}/java/lib path on the java command.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, I don't think either Roger or I are asking you about the version of Java.  My question is which version of MQ are the jar files that you use, ex `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` from, for example 9.1.0.1.  Rogers question was are you using the MQ JAR files that IBM releases for z/OS not those from Windows/Unix (I was not aware they released a different Jar for z/OS).

Comment: I found this documentation, can you confirm you have these variables set: [Installation of IBM MQ classes for Java on z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030640_.htm).

Comment: These is the MQ classes for java that I'm using: Name:        WebSphere MQ classes for Java
Version:     8.0.0.12
Level:       V800-PH11727-L190513
Build Type:  Production